# javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed Using REST Client JAX RS

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I have a problem trying to fire my webservice hosted on apache with a simple command line client using Java 8 / Eclipse / JAX RS. In my web service hosted in apache, I have a class that represent a service managing users called UserService. It contains a simple method to return a User POJO class instance when a nickname and mail is sent. The data transferring dialect is JSON (my boss is in love with JSON).

```
@Path("/UserService")
public class UserService 
{   
    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    @Path("/login")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User login(@FormParam("nickname") String nickname, @FormParam("mail") String mail)
    {       
            User loggedUser = null;

            try 
            {
                loggedUser =  _resource.login(nickname, mail);
            } 
            catch (RequesterException e) 
            {
                _logger.write(e);
            } 
            catch (ConnectionException e) 
            {
                _logger.write(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                return loggedUser;
            }
    }   
}
```

In a very simple class in command line client side, I try to push a valid nickname and mail to obtain an existing user. My URI is good, my web service started correctly in apache tomcat.

```
    public class JSONTest 
    {
        private static final String REST_URI  = "http://localhost:8080/WebServices/Texte/UserService";

        public User getloggedUser(String nickname, String mail) 
        {
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

             Form form = new Form().param("nickname", nickname).param("mail", mail);             

             return client
                  .target(REST_URI)
                  .path( "/login" )
                  .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                  .post( Entity.form(form), Player.class);       
        }   
    }
```

In a main method as entry point, I launch the test expecting my existing user.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JSONTest j = new JSONTest();
    User maxUser = j.getloggedUser("Max", "max@max.com");
}
```

But I obtain a big exception: I do not understand because I post a form to a webservice expecting a post with form parameters. I certainly make a mistake somewhere but after searching and trying many things, I am stuck.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1011)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:816)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:696)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:448)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:349)
```

Comment: Please edit your question, separate code and text.

Comment: Are you sure you send with POST method. Can you show how you send request?

Comment: I'm ashamed but I make a very stupid mistake. In fact my boss force me to learn REST web service to add it on a app as I am an absolute beginners on it. So to have a working example, I download a source code from an expert on the web that works perfectly. After having made some customizations, I migrate this sample to make my own code. But in Eclipse, the modifications I made to test rely on the old sample. So on one hand I made the correct code but on the other hand on the bad piece of code : this is why it could not work :)

Comment: I am a very newbie on posting on this board so please excuse me if i paste the code not gently. I want to thank people taking time to read my post and try to help me : you are fabulous people thanks. Is there somewhere a button to say this post is solved ?

Comment: @WebTarget you can share the solution as an self-posted answer and then accept your answer as the solution.